# Sequential upload / serial queue with alamofire

Tags: swift, queue, alamofire, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using `Alamofire` and a serial `DispatchQueue` to try and upload one image at a time from an array of images. I would like to upload one at a time so I can update a single progress HUD as each upload goes through. My code looks something like this:

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "project.serialQueue")
for image in images {
    serialQueue.async {
        uploadImage(image: image, progress: { progress in 
            //update progress HUD
        }, completion: { json, error in 
            //dismiss HUD
        })
    }
}
```

The problem is that my `uploadImage()` calls are all executing at once.  I think this is because `Alamofire` requests are run asynchronously. Any ideas on how to best solve this?

Comment: same with `serialQueue.sync {` ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan Yes, .sync { } is same result, all uploads run at once

Comment: FYI, you pay a significant performance penalty uploading them sequentially. Just implement the HUD to handle simultaneous uploads (e.g. a hierarchy of [`Progress`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress) objects seem like the logical solution to me). But don't sacrifice performance for the sake of the HUD. (And, btw, you preclude the use of background sessions if you initiate them sequentially.)

Comment: @Rob what kind of performance penalty occurs? Also, what did you mean by precluding the use of background sessions? AFAIK, Alamofire's request calls are performed on background threads anyway.

Comment: The performance penalty is not due to foreground/background, but rather network latency, which sequential uploads magnify. Test it. In my quick test, uploading 100 images, averaging about 200kb each, was that it was roughly twice as slow uploading them sequentially rather than concurrently. Your mileage may vary, but I suspect you’ll see material performance difference doing them sequentially rather than concurrently.

Comment: Regarding background sessions, you want to make sure that all the upload requests are submitted before the user leaves the app. (If user leaves app while one app upload is in progress, then the app won’t be running to respond to completion and initiate a just-in-time request for the next upload.) And if you have background session fire-up your app when the previous upload finishes, then (a) that’s overhead; and (b) uploads initiated while running in the background are going to be discretionary (you cannot initiate non-discretionary tasks from background mode).

Answer (score 2):

Alamofire runs in his own background queue , so You can try

```
var counter = 0
func uploadImg(_ img:UIImage) {
    uploadImage(image: img, progress: { progress in 
        //update progress HUD
    }, completion: { json, error in 
        //dismiss HUD
        self.counter += 1
        if self.counter < images.count {
           self.uploadImg(images[counter])
        }
    })
}
```

Call

```
uploadimg(images.first!)
```